# Excel formula to exclude date range with start and end dates for SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Am new here, may i ask how to use SUMIFS to exclude a date range, but provided only start and end date of that date range

Comment: like `=SUMIFS(SumColumn,DateColumn,">="&FromDate,DateColumn,"<="& ToDate)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments, but isnt that the formula for include only the date range? Mine is for excluding

Comment: To exclude you need to substract sums this from total sum. Can you show some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Am still new to the site so i dont know how to include my sheet yet. But put it simply, i want to sum the hours worked that is below the standard hour (which is 8) for employees on Sundays and Holidays. i managed to handle the Sunday part, simply putting individual Sundays of the month into the SUMIFS. But for the Holidays, i only have a table of start day and end day of the Holidays. My expected result is for if there is a Sunday which accidentaly is a Holidays, and an employee decide to work in that day, only the sum of the holiday would be calculated, the sum of Sunday wouldnt count that in

Comment: i hope you get my point, Eng is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand your setup & all of your requirements. But here is my suggestion based on how I interpreted your description. Please let me know if I misunderstood anything and I will try to fix it.

[Example Workbook: SUMIFS Holiday Sunday](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmcGUE_vrclQ7xk0v3laeKoLK5YZ?e=VNjFZa)